# Learning CRUD ASP.net mvc4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, crud

Currently converting my mvc windows forms app into a asp.net mvc4. MY database consists of four different tables. I can create crud controllers based on any table in the db as well as the view as i understand. I taught one could create a single controller with crud for all tables but does not seem possible?! I was wondering this as i want my views to be able to CRUD more than one table? How does one do this? The only way i could do this i think is to create my respective views/pages accessible by action methods from the Home controller. Then each of these views could redirect to a specific CRUD controller created for each table? Thanks for any suggestions in advance. Also any links or posts that could help my luarning path would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Take a look at Model-View-Controller pattern and Single Responsibility principle. There are no restrictions to use 1, 2 or 10 views editing 1, 2 or 4 entities lists (tables), because according to MVC presentations is completely independent from logic and according to SRP every class\unit must realize the only one concept - presentation\storage\logic concept. 2. Please, form your question in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to follow the advice in another post :[Pass more than one model to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031132/pass-more-than-one-model-to-view)

Also as regards CRUD methods, for the time being i will use the classes i have already created in the previous incarnation of my project as a windows forms mvc.