# Returning more than just one model to the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am fairly new to MVC, and I've been reading a bit about ViewModels, but how do I go about sending two models to my View, where the queries are like so

```
    public ActionResult Index(int Id)
    {
        var People = from a in db.Person
                     select a;

        var Data = from a in db.Member
                   where a.Person.PersonId.Equals(Id)
                   select new
                   {
                       a.Project.ProjectId,
                       a.Project.Name,
                       a.Project.Customer,

                       a.Project.TechProfile.Select(x => new
                       {
                           x.TechId,
                           x.Name,
                           x.Elements
                       }),

                       a.MemberId,
                       a.Role,
                       a.Start,
                       a.End
                   };

        return View(People);
    }
```

I was using `@model IQueryable<GeoCV.Models.Person>` before so I could use a `@foreach` in my View but I don't know how to get my other query to the View so I can get data from it too.

---

**Update**

And I'm making a custom class for my Data query, but I don't know how to set the property of `TechProfile`

Right now I have

```
public IEnumerable<TechProfile> ProjectTechProfile { get; set; }
```

In my custom class, but it doesn't work, so I guess I have to specify `TechId`, `Name` and `Elements`?
But how?

Comment: create a ViewModel for it

Comment: You view model needs to contain properties `IEnumerable<Person>` and another property for a type returned your second query (create a separate view model for it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass more than one model to view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031132/pass-more-than-one-model-to-view)

Comment: How do I go about creating a ViewModel for it?

Comment: [Pass more than one model to view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031132/pass-more-than-one-model-to-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ViewModel wraps around the 2 models you are getting with your 2 queries, so you can return it as a single object to your view. In your case we need to adress another issue first. You are returning an anonymous object in your data query.

This means, your data query needs to return a strongly typed object instead of an anonymous object.

Create a class for your data query:

```
public class MyCustomDataObject
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    //... map all properties as needed
}
```

then edit your data query to return this object:

```
    var Data = from a in db.Member
               where a.Person.PersonId.Equals(Id)
               select new MyCustomDataObject
               {
                   ProjectId =  a.Project.ProjectId,
                   //assign all properties
               };
```

Now you need to create the actual ViewModel class:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyCustomDataObject> Data { get; set; }
}
```

And after this you just need to assign the values to it in your Actionmethod:

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id)
{
    var People = from a in db.Person
                 select a;

    var Data = from a in db.Member
               where a.Person.PersonId.Equals(Id)
               select new MyCustomDataObject
               {
                   ProjectId = a.Project.ProjectId,
                   //...
               };

    //store data of both queries in your ViewModel class here:
    var vm = new MyCustomDataObject();
    vm.Persons = People;
    vm.Data = Data  
    //return ViewModel to View.
    return View(vm);
}
```

And then declare it in your view: `@model Namespace.Subfolder.MyCustomDataObject`

Comment: I hit a snag when creating a class for my data query, the place where I have `TechProfile` I don't know how to assign in my class. I made it like `public IEnumerable<TechProfile> ProTechProfile { get; set; }` but it doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work? Don't forget that you need to select it strongly typed too! `.Select(x => new Techprofile { TechId = x.TechId, ...})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Html.Action("actionName","controllerName")` method in view. You can divide your original view into multiple partial view and then you can render that partial view with dynamic model binding using `@Html.Action("actionName","controllerName")` method.

For more details with sample code http://devproconnections.com/development/how-use-aspnet-mvc-render-action-helpers

Answer (score 0):

You can have methods like below to get multiple model in single view

```
private IList<People> GetPeople()
{
    return from a in db.Person
                 select a;
}

private IList<Data> GetData()
{
    return from a in db.Member
               where a.Person.PersonId.Equals(Id)
               select new
               {
                   a.Project.ProjectId,
                   a.Project.Name,
                   a.Project.Customer,

                   a.Project.TechProfile.Select(x => new
                   {
                       x.TechId,
                       x.Name,
                       x.Elements
                   }),

                   a.MemberId,
                   a.Role,
                   a.Start,
                   a.End
               };

}

public ActionResult Index(int Id)
{
    var MultipleModel = new Tuple<IList<People>,IList<Data>>(GetPeople(),GetData()) { };
    return View(MultipleModel);
}
```

Here's [a codeproject tutorial on the subject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC).